# How to share AWS AppSync GraphQL schema?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I defined schema.graphql within my Flutter app, but another app will use some generated tables (DynamoDB) of this model. I am using the code below, the same of AWS official tutorial (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/flutter#data-schema).

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  status: PostStatus!
  rating: Int
  content: String
}

enum PostStatus {
  DRAFT
  PUBLISHED
}
```

Is there a way to share the same GraphQL schema among applications? Or should I somehow export GraphQL models of my DynamoDB tables and update manually the schema.graphql in each app?